# Python - how to get async result?

Tags: python, rest, asynchronous, async-await, aiohttp

I have code for async REST API requests which should make quite a lot of asynchronous API requests (independent from each other), gather JSONs from results and return a list. I'm using `asyncio` and `aiohttp` for asynchronous bits.

My code:

```
async def async_get_clients_events(
    client: ApiClient,
    client_tokens: List[ClientToken]
):
    async with ClientSession() as session:
        tasks = [
            async_get_single_organization_events(
                client, ct.client_id, ct.private_token, session
            )
            for ct in client_tokens
        ]

        results = await asyncio.gather(*tasks)

    return results


async def async_get_single_client_events(
    client: ApiClient,
    client_id: str,
    api_key: Optional[str] = None,
    session: ClientSession = None,
) -> List[Dict]:
    if api_key is not None:
        headers = get_default_headers()
        headers["Authorization"] = "Bearer " + client.api_key
    else:
        headers = get_default_headers()

    # prepare request parameters, a bit of code omitted

    events = await asyncio.gather(async_get(session, url, headers, return_json=True))

    return events


async def async_get(
    session: ClientSession,
    url: str,
    headers: Dict[str, str] = None,
    params: Dict[str, Any] = None,
    return_json: bool = True,
) -> ClientResponse:
    headers = headers if headers is not None else {}
    params = params if params is not None else {}

    response = await session.request(
        method="GET", url=url, headers=headers, params=params
    )
    response.raise_for_status()
    if return_json:
        return await response.json()
    else:
        return response
```

**Question:** how can I gather results in `async_get_clients_events`? I just want the requests to be asynchronous, after that I want to wait for all results and gather them.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that async functions in Python are not functions, but coroutines and they are **not run when called**. They are more like class objects and require separate method call for actually executing them.

The above code was executed with `async_get_clients_events(client, client_tokens)` call, which I thought was obviously right. It's not. The fixed verion:

```
task = async_get_organizations_events(self, organizations_tokens)
results = asyncio.run(task)
```

SO questions I got this from: [link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44048536/python3-get-result-from-async-method), [link 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55756888/sys1-runtimewarning-coroutine-was-never-awaited).